# Any VBNET equivalence of C# where generic constraint keyword?

Tags: generics, .net-2.0, c#-to-vb.net

First, I wish to write myself a generic type for operations against the underlying Active Directory.

For those of you who know about AD and the [System.DirectoryServices namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx), the [DirectoryEntry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) is the top most important along with the DirectorySearcher class.

When speaking the AD language, everything is a [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx). With that said, my application needs to manage Users, Groups and Organizational Units (OU). Each of these objects are AD entries. Then, this sounds to me a good candidate for [GenericTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx).

What I wish to accomplish is this:

```
public interface ITop {
    string Path { get; set; }
    string ObjectClass { get; }
    string ContainerName { get; set; }
    // [...]
}

public interface IGroup : ITop {
    // Speciality properties here...
}

public interface IUser : ITop {
    // Speciality properties here...
}

// And so forth...

public sealed class DirectorySource<T> where T : ITop {
    // Methods against AD here...
}
```

My class library MUST respond to the following organical criterion:

1. VS2005 VBNET
2. .NET 2.0
3. Active Directory
4. Windows Forms

Well, I guess I have already given too much details for the purpose of my question, but any suggestion on the architecture and design patterns are welcome as well. My question is:

Is there a VBNET 2.0 equivalence of [C# where (generic type constraint)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) keyword, or any best practice workarounds?

The results of my searches seem to end with the undoable conclusion. So I'm asking...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Like this:

```
Public Class DirectorySource(Of T As ITop)
```

Multiple constraints are enclosed by braces, like this:

```
Public Class DirectorySource(Of T As { ITop, IDisposable, Class, New })
```

Comment: You would think that it would be something like this 
`Of T As One Of The Following Items ITop, IDisposable, Class, New`

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Generic constraints are anded, not ored.