# VB.Net Generics Constraints Equivalent to C# where TValue : New()

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, extension-methods

I am working on converting an extension method I have in C# into VB.Net, but can't figure out the correct way to set a constraint on the output.

My current C# code is working on a Dictionary and looks as follows:

```
public static TValue GetOrCreate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
    where TValue : new()
{   }
```

I've seen questions explaining how to set the constraint on the **inputs** such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803933/any-vbnet-equivalence-of-c-sharp-where-generic-constraint-keyword), but I can't seem to find one explaining how to convert the **output** constraint of `where TValue : new()`

I'm sure it's easy, but I've grown a bit rusty with VB and hoping someone here knows it off the top of their head.

Comment: [VB.Net Generic Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-procedures) - the constraints go directly inside the `(Of ...)` between procedure name and argument list. See the example `Public Function findElement(Of T As IComparable)`

Comment: The syntax is actually the same for inputs and outputs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256115/1968

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any VBNET equivalence of C# where generic constraint keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803933/any-vbnet-equivalence-of-c-sharp-where-generic-constraint-keyword)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the conversion, as obtained from Telerik's [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/):

```vb
Module Extensions
  <Extension()>
  Public Function GetOrCreate(Of TKey, TValue As New)(ByVal dict As IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue), ByVal key As TKey) As TValue

  End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Beat me to it by about 30 seconds.

Comment: WOOHOO!!! - The trick was the `GetOrCreate(Of TKey, TValue As New)` - Thank you!!!

Comment: I saw people's comments, but none of them made sense / worked - THIS gave me the answer. Thank you!!

Comment: Also: there was an edit to remove the `Shared` modifier, which I rolled back. `Shared` should be removed if the method is part of a Module, but is still needed if the method is part of Class. Since this code is being converted from C#, I believe the latter is more likely.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Was already typing a response separately, just took a minute to have it ready.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Correct me if I'm wrong but a VB extension method _**Must**_ be defined in a module as I mentioned in the edit message.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Generally that is true, but IIRC there are ways around it. But maybe those required reflection games or similar. It's been a while.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ~ To clarify the `Shared` situation, I edited the code a bit.

Comment: @JohnBustos ~ YW  :-)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed ~ `... a VB extension method Must be defined in a module ...` Yes, that's correct. In my experience, at least. I've not experimented with putting one in a class as Joel suggests might be possible. In any event, I haven't run across a situation that would make it worth the extra trouble. Modules are easy. So easy, in fact, that I created three of them yesterday ;-)